# Integration of mixed sin and cos functions - can't find it

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

I can't remember the question that was posted around Feb 2nd,2022
I presume that it has been deleted by some reasons
The question was : 
$$
\int \frac{\sin (\cos x)}{\cos(\sin x)} dx
$$

can anyone answer, or find the question?

*edit :

So my answer was (didn't signed it up) (well not "my" answer")
$$
\frac{\sin(\cos x)}{\cos x}\log_{e}|\sec (\sin x) + \tan (\sin x)|
$$

process :

let $$t = \sin x$$
then the question can be fixed as :
$$\int \frac{\sin (\cos x)}{\cos t} dx$$
also, $dt = dx \cos x$,
the question can be fixed again to : 
$$
\int \frac{\sin(\cos x)}{\cos t} \frac{1}{\cos x} dt$$
$$= \frac{\sin(\cos x)}{\cos x}\int \sec t dt$$
$$= \frac{\sin(\cos x)}{\cos x}\log_{e}|\sec t + \tan t|$$

and finally, 
$$\frac{\sin(\cos x)}{\cos x}\log_{e}|\sec (\sin x) + \tan (\sin x)|$$
am I right? If I am right, can I fix it easier? If I am wrong, why?

Comment: Are you sure that the problem was not a definite integral (probably from $0$ to $\pi$)  ?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I fixed my question

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici When I saw it lastly, it wasn't. The writer could have changed it

Comment: May I confess that your steps look strange (at least to me).

Comment: Check by differentiation! You take $\frac{\sin(\cos(x))}{\cos(x)}$ out of the  integral, but $x$ depends on $t$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that your result is correct.

Being lazy, what I did is a series expansion of the integrand
$$\sin (\cos (x)) \sec (\sin (x))=\sin (1)+\frac{\sin (1)-\cos (1)}{2}  x^2-\frac{2 \sin (1)+5 \cos (1)}{24}x^4 +O\left(x^6\right)$$
Then, doing the same with your expression  and differentiating it,
$$\sin (1)+\frac{3(\sin (1)-\cos (1))}{2} x^2 +\frac{6 \sin (1)-25 \cos (1)}{24} x^4 +O\left(x^6\right)$$